# Woocommerce Cart - maximum purchase quantity from certain category by user roles

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am wondering if I can add some sort of code to my woocommerce store to set accumulated maximum purchase quantity from a category for certain user role.

For example,

3 user roles: A, B, C

3 product categories: 1,2,3

I want to limit roles A to only purchase maximum of 2 products from Cat 1 throughout the lifetime of their membership, while still able to purchase any amount of product from Cat2,3

Meanwhile for roles B and C, the logic is pretty much same but the maximum accumulated quantity will be different.

Is that possible to write some sort of code in function php?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation`.
For example:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', function($valid, $product_id, $quantity) {
    $cat_id = CAT_ID; // CAT_ID ----YOUR category id
    $your_quantity = YOUR_QUANTITY;
    $user_role = YOUR_USER_ROLE;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_roles = $user->roles;
    if(!in_array($user_role, $user_roles)) {
      return $valid;
    }
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $current_product_categories = $product->get_category_ids();

    //check if quantity is bigger than allowed
    if(in_array($cat_id, $current_product_categories) && $quantity > $your_quantity) {
        return false;
    }

    //Counter for products in cart and orders.
    $counter = 0;
    //check whole cart
    $cart_items          = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    foreach($cart_items as $cart_key => $cart_data) {
        $product = wc_get_product($cart_data['product_id']);
        $cart_product_categories = $product->get_category_ids();
        if(in_array($cat_id, $cart_product_categories)) { 
            $counter = $counter + 1 * $cart_data['quantity'];
        }
    }
    if($counter > $your_quantity) {
        return false;
    }
    //All user's orders
    $user_orders = wc_get_orders(array(
    'customer' => get_current_user_id( )
    ));
    
    if($user_orders->total > 0) {
        foreach($user_orders as $order) {
            $products = $order->get_items('line_item');
            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $product_categories = $product->get_category_ids();
                if(in_array($cat_id, $product_categories)) { 
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if($counter > $your_quantity) {
        return false;
    }
    return $valid;
    }, 10, 3);
```

You can also place `wc_add_notice()` when you `return false`;